# Unable to dereference vector iterators

Tags: c++, vector, iterator, dereference

I don't understand what the problem with this function is, I've done something very similar to this in the past and it worked fine, but now when I try to run this function I get the error

```
"Unable to dereference vector iterator"
```

It comes on the line `curr->setName(new_name);` which makes sense since that's where its being dereferenced.  Also just to be clear all the functions and classes used in this method work fine on their own, I'm just not inserting them for the sake of space.

```
void System::modify(PC a){
    char x;
    curr = find(begin(comps), end(comps), a);

    cout << "What would you like to modify:" << endl;
    cout << "a - Name" << endl;
    cout << "b - IP" << endl;
    cout << "c - Password" << endl;

    cin >> x;
    if(x == 'a'){
        string new_name;
        cout << "What would you like to rename the computer to: ";
        cin >> new_name;
        curr->setName(new_name);
    }

    if(x == 'b'){
        string new_IP;
        cout << "What would you like the new IP address to be: ";
        cin >> new_IP;
        curr->setIP(new_IP);
    }

    if(x == 'c'){
        curr->setNewPass();
    }

    else{
        cout << "Choice is not valid" << endl;
        return;
    }
}
```

Comment: did you check to make sure `curr != end(comps)` and that comps is not empty?

Comment: @NathanOliver Obviously not.

Comment: You should check `curr != end(comps)` and decide what to do with a non existing PC

Answer (score 2):

You need to modify your function - it should check, whether `find()` has found something at all:

```
void System::modify(PC a){
    char x;
    curr = find(begin(comps), end(comps), a);

    if(curr == end(comps))
    {
        cout << "Specified PC was not found!" << endl;
        return;
    }

    //...
}
```

Documentation page for [find()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/find/) says:

> **Return value**
>
> An iterator to the first element in the range that compares equal to val. **If no elements match, the function returns `last`.**

Where `last` in this case is `end(comps)`.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that value `a` was not found in this statement

```
curr = find(begin(comps), end(comps), a);
```

and `curr` is equal to `end(comps)` .

You should check that the search was successfull.

For example

```
if ( ( curr = find(begin(comps), end(comps), a) ) != end(comps) )
{
    // the search was successfull
}
```

Answer (score 0):

it's not clear how the PC could be compared. But it seems that find function returns end(comps), that means that there is no "PC a" in the list/vector/whatever. You should check that PC a has been found by

```
if(curr!=end(comps)) {
// do whatever you wont with corr
}
else {
//nothing has been found
}
```